# Curl login in bash

Tags: bash, post, cookies, curl, authentication

I am trying to log into a website using curl in bash, with no succes. Here is my program.

```
curl --request GET 'http://www.banggood.com/login.php' \
--cookie-jar cjar \
--output /dev/null

curl --request POST 'http://www.banggood.com/login.php?action=login' \
--data 'email_address=my_email&password=my_pass' \
--referer 'http://www.banggood.com' \
--location \
--cookie cjar \
--cookie-jar cjar

rm cjar
```

The strange thing is: when I provide incorrect login information, it behaves like normal and tells me that e-mail/password incorrect. However, when I provide the right credentials, the answer is: Bad request.

I tried setting the user agent and modifying the referer. I have no idea what could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does banggood.com normally redirect you when you login? Are there possibly headers that you're not setting that cause the site to bail on you?

Comment: No, it's not a porn site:D It usually redirects me, but it should follow redirections because of --location, or not?

Comment: Try adding ;auto to the end of your referrer. Also, curl doesn't pass login credentials through the redirect by default. Perhaps if you try to go directly to the redirected page first instead of banggood.com, or add --location-trusted.

Comment: I've tried your suggestions, but it's not working. It always gives me the "bad request" error or just redirects me back to the login page. Maybe there is something wrong with the cookies?

Comment: I'm out of suggestions. Perhaps running tcpdump while you browse there in a normal browser so you can see if there's something else going on with the HTTP headers that you need to add?

Comment: I'm now trying to reproduce the headers exactly as Firefox sends them.

Comment: After capturing some packets with wireshark, I found that there was a redirect which was not followed properly by curl. I wrote another POST request in the script and now it is working. Thank you for the guidance!